# React (w/ react-redux) caching options

Tags: reactjs, caching, redux, react-redux

I'm building an app where the user logs in and can see a number of stats.

Each stat will be the result of an API call - think of a table with several columns, each column containing a stat (just a number).

I've noticed that each time the component is re-rendered, the API call is made again. This has major performance issues because it can take a few milliseconds for the stat to appear. How do I:

a) Cache this information so that it persists and does not need to be re-called on every render,
b) Make the app "know" when to re-call the API, because the stat has updated in the database?

I'm currently using Redux to store more obvious stuff, like which campaign the user is viewing, but surely there is a better way to cache these stats than to create actions and reducers for every one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am using Redux the answer to this wasn't as simple as I would have liked. Using the answer above I worked out the solution.

Firstly when the component mounts it performs an API call which in turns fires an action, then the reducer, which then updates the store.

Secondly, I'm using `shouldComponentUpdate` like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.value){
        return true
    }
    if(this.props.value){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If the component has nextProps, re-render. If it already has a value, don't re-render, and if it doesn't (have props) render.

I am still calling the API using `componentDidMount()` which is effectively listening each time the component is used, and the decision to render (or not) is made by the shouldComponentUpdate() method.

Answer (score 3):

a) For caching your data into localStorage watch this [video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage) by **Dan Abramov** (author of redux)

b) To avoid rerender of your component use **shouldComponentUpdate**

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  /**If no change in state return false*/
  return this.state.value != nextState.value;
}
```

In this way you can stop unnecassary rerendering.

Answer (score 1):

In essence you need to handle every fetch action in redux reducer. That's why (after implementing caching a couple of times) I decided to publish a library ([redux-cached-api-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-cached-api-middleware)), specifically designed to help in such cases (it's a thin wrapper on top of [redux-api-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware)). You only need to think of unique cache key for every request.

Here's an example component, that fetches items from an API and uses 10 minute caching strategy (this means that if you try to invoke the API while cache is valid it will just return the data from the cache):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import api from 'redux-cached-api-middleware';
import Items from './Items';
import Error from './Error';

class ExampleApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    const { result } = this.props;
    if (!result) return null;
    if (result.fetching) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    if (result.error) return <Error data={result.errorPayload} />;
    if (result.successPayload) return <Items data={result.successPayload} />;
    return <div>No items</div>;
  }
}

ExampleApp.propTypes = {
  fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  result: PropTypes.shape({}),
};

const CACHE_KEY = 'GET/items';

const enhance = connect(
  state => ({
    result: api.selectors.getResult(state, CACHE_KEY),
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    fetchData() {
      return dispatch(
        api.actions.invoke({
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
          endpoint: 'https://my-api.com/items/',
          cache: {
            key: CACHE_KEY,
            strategy: api.cache
              .get(api.constants.CACHE_TYPES.TTL_SUCCESS)
              .buildStrategy({ ttl: 10 * 60 * 1000 }), // 10 minutes
          },
        })
      );
    },
  })
);

export default enhance(ExampleApp);
```

And the setup for library is as follows:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { apiMiddleware } from 'redux-api-middleware';
import api from 'redux-cached-api-middleware';
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    [api.constants.NAME]: api.reducer,
  }),
  applyMiddleware(thunk, apiMiddleware)
);
```